# How can I remove background lines from polar chart by react chart js 2?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have this polar chart [image: this polar chart] from react chart js 2. I want these (pointed with red arrow) background lines to be removed. Is it possible to remove these lines? I have tried several solutions like changing background lines image color to background etc. Here is codebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wood-2xpk3p?file=/App.tsx. Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see you are getting TS errors because you are using V2 syntax, if you configure your options in the following way it works fine:

```
const chartOptions = {
  scales: {
    r: {
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-tree-8gdqxg?file=/App.tsx